# Automatic injection of templated html into razor section based on view folder

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Say i have several views in several folders.

And there is a menu, which will have different things in it depending on the view folder.

Is there a way to template out a menu in a file (in a `@section` or something) and have it automatically injected into the main template? (probably /views/shared/_layout.cshtml).

i.e. something like

**/views/foo/menu.cshtml**

```
@section menu
{
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2</li>
}
```

**/views/bar/menu.cshtml**

```
@section menu
{
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>  
}
```

**/views/shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
<blah blah blah>
<ul>
@if(IsSectionDefined("Menu"))
{
    @RenderSection("Menu");
}
</ul>
@RenderBody()
</blah blah blah>
```

So if localhost/foo/* is called foo/menu will be injected. 
If localhost/bar/* is called bar/menu will be injected into _Layout and so on and so forth.

I'm thinking 2 possible injection points are in the _ViewStart.cshtml or overriding the base webpage class, but the question remains, how to inject the section?

Thanks to SLaks added this to _Layout.cshtml:

```
@{
    var controller = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    if (File.Exists(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + @"\views\" + controller + @"\menu.cshtml"))
    { 
        @Html.Partial("~/views/" + controller + "/menu.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/" + name + "/menu.cshtml")
```